# Make Notepad++ custom file extension as Normal Text

Tags: notepad++

I have a custom file extension, and Notepad++ does some weird coloration to it by default. I want N++ to treat every file with this extension as "Normal Text" language. I know can where I would maybe change it from Settings > Style Configurator > Language, but "Normal Text" isn't listed in the list of languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension is presumably listed in the `langs.xml` file as an associated default extension for a particular language.

You can remove a default extension by opening the `langs.xml` file in the Notepad++ data directory. This directory depends on your settings, but is generally either in the same folder as the Notepad++ installation or in `%APPDATA%\Notepad++`.

As an example, the default extensions for ActionScript are listed in the `ext` field of the `<Language name="actionscript">` element.

```
<Language name="actionscript" ext="as mx" commentLine="//" commentStart="/*" commentEnd="*/">
```

You can remove the extension by simply deleting it here, saving the file and then restarting Notepad++.

The one drawback about this is that you would likely need to repeat this step after any Notepad++ update that updates the `langs.xml` file.

Comment: `%AppData%\Roaming\Notepad++` is not correct.  `%AppData%` expands to `c:\users\<name>\AppData\Roaming` already (*), so that resolves to `c:\users\<name>\AppData\Roaming\Roaming\Notepad++`.  (see [wayback of MS link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180606140951/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/help/folder-variables) = Vista, 7, 8.1, 10; see also [ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) and [wikipedia Environment variables article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Environment_variable&oldid=884762930#Default_values) )